# Converting JSON to entities and storing in mongoDB using morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, entity, morphia, nosql

I have a JSON string being sent from a client (browser ).I want to save it to my mongoDB database which already has some collections defined by the user.I was able to successfully save objects using Morphia.But How can I do the same if I already have the JSON string being returned from client I want to put in the "bands" collection.

```
        Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost");
        Datastore datastore = new Morphia().createDatastore(mongo,
                "bandmanager");
        Band band = new Band();
        band.setName("Punjabi band");
        band.getMembers().add("Lucky1");
        band.getMembers().add("Lucky2");
        band.getMembers().add("Lucky3");
        band.getMembers().add("Lucky4");
        band.getMembers().add("Lucky5");
        band.getMembers().add("Lucky6");
        band.setGenre("Punjabi");
        datastore.save(band);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you annotate Band with `@Entity("bands")`?  I'm not sure what you're asking...  Are you asking how to convert that json string in to a Band object?  If so, look in to [jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome)

Comment: I did annotate Band with @Entity.SO I was thinking why do I have to parse the JSON I get from the client and then set the Band object to be stored as a JSON again.Hope you understand.

Comment: Well, morphia deals with java objects so if you're using morphia, you'll need to map that json to your java objects one way or another.  Alternatively, you could take the Map generated from those json documents and pass them to the java driver directly.  At that point, it'd be up to you to make sure all the document keys are mapped properly and the values are typed correctly.  That'd be "faster" execution-wise potentially, but a lot more work up front and maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a JSON object, you don't really need Morphia. You can simply do the following with the Java driver:

```
DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(yourJsonString);
```

For a full blog post on this see http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-convert-json-data-to-dbobject/

PS: Do not forget to sanitize the JSON you get from the client!